# Do we still need AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas() in Global.asax in pure ASP.NET Web API service without MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create a clean ASP.NET Web API service without referencing MVC assemblies if possible.
I followed this blog http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615805/Creating-a-Clean-Minimal-Footprint-ASP-NET-WebAPI
but with this line in Global.asax I still have to import System.Web.Mvc assembly. Would there be an impact in my web api service if I removed it? I tried running my service in my local without it and I did not encounter any error.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
        //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); do we still need this?

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);  
        HandlerConfig.RegisterGlobalHandlers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters);            

}
```

Comment: If you are not using Areas no registration is required.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're not using MVC areas then there should be no need to call `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()`