# Shouldn't OwinStartupAttribute run before global.asax and Application_Start?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I need to run code before application start and up until now I have used WebActivator to do that but if I understand correctly the `OwinStartupAttribute` is more suitable for that but the problem for me is that it runs after `Application_Start` in `Global.asax`, is this correct or can I configure it to run pre application start?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this answer it runs slightly after Application_Start. So if you, just like me need to run code before Application_Start, WebActivator is still the way to go I guess. [Do I need a Global.asax.cs file at all if I'm using an OWIN Startup.cs class and move all configuration there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168978/do-i-need-a-global-asax-cs-file-at-all-if-im-using-an-owin-startup-cs-class-and)