# Why is Application_Start in Global.asax called before Configuration in Startup class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, startup, owin

As I understand, **Configuration** method in Owin Startup is associated with **PreApplicationStart** event. So isnt that **Configuration** method should be called *before* **Application_Start** of **Global.asax**? I am observing that Configuration method is called after Application_Start method. Can somebody throw some light as to why is this?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998796/shouldnt-owinstartupattribute-run-before-global-asax-and-application-start