# How to make the server use the startup.cs instead of Global.asax.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, server

I am trying to publish an app in the web but the server searches for Global.asax.cs and I deleted that file and added startup.cs instead.

How can I make the server search for startup.cs instead of Global.asax.cs, or what is the best approach to fix this issue ?

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for maybe here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20200895/4932743

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the Owin package from Nuget and use a startup class looks like this:

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(YOURNAMESPACE.Startup))]
namespace YOURNAMESPACE
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //DO your stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have this file. But when I push the project into the test server it searches for the global.asax.cs  but I deleted because I added the startup.cs file. How can I configure the server to search for the startup.cs instead of the global.asax.cs

Comment: I think there's no reason to delete the global.asax.cs. If you have a startup class like this it uses this.

Comment: Hmm so I should add the global.asax.cs and have the startup.cs as well. 
OK I thank you .. I will try it and see if it works :)