# Upgrade existing project to use Roslyn compiler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I installed VS 2015 and imported an existing solution. This solution contains a Razor helper in the App_Code folder.  The Error List complains:

> The type or namespace name 'global_asax' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'ASP' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

After a bit of research, I found that this is (or was) a known issue (cf. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30502263/1637105) and [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/05/12/enabling-the-net-compiler-platform-roslyn-in-asp-net-applications.aspx)). The solution given in those articles is to manually install the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` NuGet package.

So I installed that NuGet package in my web app project, and the error went away.

But now I get an error when I open the Package Manager Console complaining that it can't copy some file. The (incorrect) path to the missing file is given in the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` NuGet package configuration info.

**All of this leads me to believe that there must be a better way!**

Am I missing something? Shouldn't I get the new Roslyn magic automagically via VS 2015? If not, is there some better way for me to install it into my existing project? Or am I just stumbling over broken infrastructure bits that someone needs to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this MSDN blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/12/07/new-feature-to-enable-c-6-vb-14.aspx) the solution is, in fact, to install the Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform package (which, I hope and assume, they have fixed since I tried that in July, 2015).  There is even some magic baked into the VS 2015 UI to install that package via the Project menu.

Answer (score 2):

I created a new MVC app in VS 2015 and stared at the NuGet packages it installs. Turns out that we apparently need to install the

`Microsoft.Net.Compilers` NuGet package

(rather than the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` package).

EDIT: And after a bit more fiddling around with this solution, it appears to be no better than the (failed) solution I gave in the OP.  But fear not, there is apparently a answer (if you are running VS 2015).  I'll post that as a separate answer.