# Nuget package manager update 3.1.1.0 broken

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I updated Nuget package manager to version 3.1.1.0. After the update opening any project gives me the error message:
copy-item: cannot find path 'c:\users{username}\documents\visual studio 2015\projects{project name}\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\tools\lib\net45' because it does not exist ..... 
in file init.ps1

I found $installpath variable given to init.ps1 differs from old nuget to actual in additionally appended \tools subdirectory name, which is obviously wrong and gives the error.

How can I influence this $installpath parameter or downgrade nuget to 3.1.0?

I double-checked this behaviour also in a fresh installed vm with the same result, VS installed -> ok, update to nuget 3.1.1 -> broken.

Environment: Windows 10 German, Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition English

Comment: I would open an issue on [NuGet's GitHub](https://github.com/nuget/home) site about the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1125#issuecomment-128503074.

Answer (score 31):

Not sure if this will help others, but I got the exact same error on VS2015 with Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform and what fixed it for me was to do the following in the Package Manager Console:

```sh
Update-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

Then after saving, closing and reopening VS, no more errors.  No need to edit any ps1 files for me.

FWIW.

Comment: I was missing the packages folder it was talking about. This happened after a force close and recovered documents so @Tod Thomson's solution didn't work for me but this did.

Comment: `DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.2` fixed it for me, was referencing `DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0` in VS 2015. Error I was receieving: _Join-Path : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'ChildPath'. Specified 
method is not supported.at .... init.ps1:13 char:57_, also _Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null ... at init.ps1:14 char:44_

Comment: Years later, I've been seeing the same issue with VS 2019.  This fix it for me.

Answer (score 20):

I got the same error as well (as follows):

```
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Development\GitHub\pd-tech-demo\backend\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\tools\lib\net45' because it does not exist.
At C:\Development\GitHub\pd-tech-demo\backend\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\tools\init.ps1:23 char:1
+ Copy-Item $libDirectory\* $binDirectory | Out-Null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Development\...tools\lib\net45:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I changed line 10 of `init.ps1` from:

```
$libDirectory = Join-Path $installPath 'lib\net45'
```

to:

```
$libDirectory = Join-Path $installPath '..\lib\net45'
```

which fixes the problem (only until you restore the package again and you get the broken version).

The real fix is for the package maintainers to update their copy of `init.ps1`. I'll follow up and see if we can get that done. :)

Comment: This is a bug in NuGet, see my comments below

Answer (score 2):

This issue is Tracked by https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1125
we are also working with the package owner to see if he can move off using init.ps1 for setting up the project. This process does not follow the NuGet guidelines, but we are not sure if there is a workaround yet.

Comment: and the fix is in flight, it will be part of the 3.1.2 release

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error in Package Manager Console and eventually found this thread.

As the error message said, the packages ...\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\tools\lib\net45 directory is missing hence the problem.

The "lib" directory is created directly under "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0" directory for some reason? When I moved the "lib" directory into "tools" directory, restart VS, error message gone.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error.
Changing line 10 of `init.ps1` to:
This did not work:

```
$libDirectory = Join-Path $installPath '..\lib\net45'
```

This did work:

```
$libDirectory = Join-Path $installPath '\lib\net45'
```