# 'global_asax' does not exist in the namespace 'ASP'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms, visual-studio-2015

I upgraded from Visual Studio 2013 Professional to 2015 Professional (Update 1) a few weeks ago. My two Web Application projects showed no errors in VS 2013's Error List window. However, they show 36 and 20 errors, respectively, in VS 2015. Both projects contain a mixture of Razor/MVC and Web Forms.

All of the errors have: 1) code `CS0234`, 2) description "`The type or namespace name 'global_asax' does not exist in the namespace 'ASP' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`", and 3) are for (compiled?) Razor helper files such as C:\Users\programmerX\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files...\Sources_App_Code\addresshelper.cshtml.72cecc2a.cs.

Two errors are generated for each Razor helper. Hence, the project with 18 helpers has 36 errors.

Opening a helper in VS will temporarily remove the two errors for that helper until the helper is closed.

The errors do not affect the building or running of the projects. They just clutter up the Error List window with false messages.

This issue is extremely similar to the questions posted at ["ASP.global_asax does not exist in the namespace ASP"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28513532/2615878) and [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1578377/the-type-or-namespace-name-global-asax-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-asp-are-you-missing-an-assembly-reference). Regrettably, none of the answers fix the problem on my computer.

Does anyone know how to eliminate (by fixing -- not suppressing) these false error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx) to suppress the Error messages. Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, I did not make it clear in my question. I want to fix the problem, not suppress the error messages (just in case there are some legitimate ones).