# OWIN Startup being called on each page request

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am implementing an NHibernate Session Factory in a WebAPI 2 project that uses OWIN. Below is a snippet of my startup class. I notice that the Startup is being called each time I load a page in my debug environment. This seems very expensive and SessionFactory should only be created once per application lifetime.

How do I avoid this? I think the repeated calls is causing problems. I am getting errors that seem related to the session factory being created multiple times within OWIN.

```
Public Class Startup
    Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(AddressOf WebApiConfig.Register)

        app.CreatePerOwinContext(AddressOf MobLib.MobDataProvider.CreateProvider)

    End Sub
End Class
```

***Update***
I've confirmed that `Configuration` is only running once, but calls to `CreateProvider` are occurring every time the page loads. Is this by design?

Comment: Hope you're not calling Configuration method of Startup class method by yourself from somewhere because it's auto-detectable.

Comment: `Configuration` is not explicitly called anywhere, only by detection.

Comment: Can you replicate this in a POC and share it? I would really want to know why this is happening because this is not usual.

Comment: Digging into it now. I was just hoping this was a stupid mistake that others had made and could enlighten me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question instead of deleting it to hide my shame - I mean, for posterity!

Everything is behaving as it should, and `CreatePerOwinContext` is quite literally doing exactly what it says. It calls the function each time a context is created. This is not what you want for something heavy like an `NHibernate SessionFactory` - especially because this can result in multiple Session Factories. I somehow thought the OWIN Context was where I should store this Singleton object, when it absolutely is not.

This makes the real question: should I put initialization code in the OWIN `Startup` method, or the `Global.asax` file. That is a completely different question, which can be seen many places. For example: [Do I need a Global.asax.cs file at all if I'm using an OWIN Startup.cs class and move all configuration there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168978/do-i-need-a-global-asax-cs-file-at-all-if-im-using-an-owin-startup-cs-class-and)