# Autofac - what is MvcApplication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm attempting to implement Autofac (first time implementing) into an ASP.NET MVC 4.5 application and the second line of code in this example already has me stumped.

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#quick-start

I'm in the Startup.cs class and configuration manager. I can't get it to recognize MvcApplication? Is that a pseudo for something? It has been in every example I can find. Did I miss a reference?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example is based on the default Visual Studio MVC template(s), which create a `Global.asax.cs` file with the following class:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
}
```

Technically, [you don't need this class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168978/do-i-need-a-global-asax-cs-file-at-all-if-im-using-an-owin-startup-cs-class-and) - you can move everthing to `Startup.cs` and delete it. The reference to the class is just to get a reference to the MVC assembly, so you can technically use any type in your MVC project (such as the `Startup` class).

Answer (score -2):

You are surely using asp.net Core and MVC6. 
If that's correct, then you don't need AutoFac; Dependency Injection is built-in by default.