# How to inject object into Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I have ASP.NET MVC 5 application with Owin.

**This is my interface:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MvcApp.Logging
{
    public interface ILog
    {
        void Debug(string format, params object[] args);
        void Error(string format, params object[] args);
        void Fatal(string format, params object[] args);
        void Info(string format, params object[] args);
        void Trace(string format, params object[] args);
        void Warn(string format, params object[] args);

        // custom
        void Write(LogType type, object properties, string message, params object[] args);

        bool IsDebugEnabled { get; }
        bool IsErrorEnabled { get; }
        bool IsFatalEnabled { get; }
        bool IsInfoEnabled { get; }
        bool IsTraceEnabled { get; }
        bool IsWarnEnabled { get; }
    }
}
```

I'm using the nuget package [Autofac.Mvc5.Owin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mvc5.Owin/) to inject ILog into the constructor of the controller. This approach it works perfectly.

**Owin Startup Class:**

```
builder.RegisterType<Log>().As<ILog>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Now I need inject ILog interface into Global.asax.cs class and Application_Start method.

Is this possible? What do I need to setup for inject ILog?

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
   // How to inject ILog here?

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
       // I need write for example this message
       ILog.Info("Application starting");
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: "Application start" -> this is where you make the app initialization  it is the same as your application startup class...

Comment: IMHO, if your app requested to database context, put it on `Application_BeginRequest` or `Application_AuthenticateRequest`, since `Application_Start` doesn't contain `HttpContext` instance.

Answer (score 0):

The Application_Start method in Global.asax runs before Owin Startup.Configuration. 
So even if you would find a way to inject ILog interface to the Application_Start method the interface would not have been resolved at that time.

Instead of using the ILog in Application_Start method, use it in the Owin Startup.Configuration method after the dependencies has been resolved.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168978/do-i-need-a-global-asax-cs-file-at-all-if-im-using-an-owin-startup-cs-class-and) a great SO question about Global.asax vs Owin Startup which is a good read